# InvalidOperationException with ToolStripDropDown

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to remove a item from a ToolStripMenuItem, but it gives me an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: the collection has changed. enumeration operation may not execute.

My code:

```
ToolStripDropDown items = main.favouritesToolStripMenuItem.DropDown;
foreach(var item in items.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()) 
{
    if (item.Text == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        main.favouritesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help i can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change a collection while you are enumerating it.

Here is a better way to do it:

```
main.favouritesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Remove(
    items.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().FirstOrDefault(
          item => item.Text == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

This will remove the first matching element as user1512185 points out, but from what I gather this is your intent anyways.

Comment: This will only remove the first element of the list which matches that condition, where it may be intended to remove ALL instances which match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are modifying the collection you are trying to enumerate.  Once you remove an item from the collection, any existing enumerators are invalidated.

You can either:

1) Exit the loop after modifying the collection

2) Iterate over a COPY of the collections by appending .ToList() to it

3) Manually iterate yourself using a for loop.  Be warned that you must understand how modifying the collection will interact with your iterator/index variable.  If you aren't careful, you can get index out of range exceptions, or skip over elements you never intended to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove items from a collection while you at the same time are iterating over the same collection in a `foreach` loop.